# How can we determine a transition point in a curve for a bar graph

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have plotted a bar graph and knowing that the transition in the curve takes place around values 21 to 25 , I want to find such point in general.

[image]

```
barplot(Views$V2,names=Views$V1,las=2,cex.names=0.2,border="blue",xpd=FALSE)
abline(v=25,col="red")
```

Any help is appreciated

**Update :**

A part of my data frame is given below. It is sorted by values V2 . By transition what I want to say is that a point in the sorted data where there is a large deviation and after which it continues in that pattern. So a point where there is difference in patterns.

```
     V1       V2
1     1 16154424
2     2  3701944
3     3  1618377
4     4   903302
5     5   569824
6     6   389772
7     7   281751
8     8   212450
9     9   166364
10   10   133339
11   11   109410
12   12    90934
13   13    77155
14   14    66124
15   15    57861
16   16    50765
17   17    44805
18   18    39996
19   19    35850
20   20    32492
21   21    29522
22   22    27152
23   23    24821
24   24    22619
25   25    21238
26   26    19639
27   27    18320
28   28    16867
29   29    15890
30   30    14936
31   31    14252
32   32    13150
33   33    12696
34   34    11656
35   35    11191
36   36    10951
37   37    10232
38   38     9605
39   39     9058
40   40     8916
41   41     8531
42   42     8010
43   43     7932
44   44     7436
45   45     6991
46   46     6750
47   47     6613
48   48     6254
49   49     6292
50   50     5731
51   51     5659
52   52     5551
53   53     5396
54   54     5122
55   55     4845
56   56     4860
57   57     4591
58   58     4504
59   59     4233
60   60     4371
61   61     4014
62   62     4083
63   63     3923
64   64     3796
65   65     3616
66   66     3519
67   67     3466
68   68     3409
69   69     3357
70   70     3215
71   71     3118
72   72     3081
73   73     3040
74   74     2951
75   75     2808
76   76     2797
77   77     2829
78   78     2714
79   79     2564
80   80     2563
81   81     2445
82   82     2528
83   83     2443
84   84     2316
85   85     2314
86   86     2212
87   87     2215
88   88     2102
89   89     2172
90   90     2020
91   91     2108
92   92     2020
93   93     2027
94   94     1982
95   95     1936
96   96     1836
97   97     1801
98   98     1850
99   99     1751
100 100     1810
```

It has to be something to do with the ratios of differences maybe and something which can be evident after observing the graph.

Comment: You really need to provide a working example. Your code does not run because you did not provide the `Views` data.frame (data.table??). Also, you have not said what you mean by "transition" and certainly it is not apparent from the image.

Comment: I'm really guessing here, but if you're looking for the first value in `$V2` that is greater than the one previous to it, perhaps `which(diff(Views$V2) > 0)[1]` will tell you that (in this case) it is row 100 (so 99 is the row you want)..

Comment: For now I have tried this when the ratios are approximately 1 , that is the point to consider. I will have to be doing some other work for now. Meanwhile if someone wants to build on that and answer it will be great.                    differences=as.data.frame(head(abs(diff(Views$V2)),100))
colnames(differences)=c("diffs")
differences$diffs differences$ratios[2:100]=as.double(differences$diffs[1:99]/differences$diffs[2:100])